# Notifying background task when content script wants

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have one main task (background.js) that runs some stuffs.

I need to create a new trigger event on the background script of my app, so that he will create a new timeout of one day (24 hours). But, i don't want to check every page i enter, on my background, What i want to do is to send some sort of "message" trough one content_script page, to my background task (the same app).

What i need: run a function on my background, from my content_script.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with message Passing. You can refer following script as a reference

## Demonstration

The following code will execute a function in background page when triggered from content script.

#### manifest.json

Registered background and content script with extension and added necessary permissions

```
{
    "name": "Run Background page function from content script",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.co.in/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.google.co.in/*"
    ]
}
```

#### background.js

It contains some trivial function and a listener for triggering call for function

```
//Some Trivial Function
function runme() {
    console.log("I am executed ... ");
}
//Listener fired when message is recieved
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (content) {
    if (content.message == "Hey i am from Google.co.in Page please run runme function") { // Check for correct message
        runme(); // Invoke function
    }
});
```

#### myscript.js

```
//Trigger background page through message passing
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    message: "Hey i am from Google.co.in Page please run runme function" //Some message
});
```

## Output

You can see background function running when trigger is invoked.

## Reference

- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).